# How to determine if a wx control is disabled

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I programmatically determine if a particular control (In my case a wx CheckBox) is disabled?  I don't see that the widget has a "disabled" property or "isDisabled" method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IsEnabled` exists, so you can do:

```
if not widget.IsEnabled():
    # do something
```

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowisenabled